# Why Angular Tutorials dont need to import Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-httpclient

If you look at the angular tutorials [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses), they do not import observable like everyone else has to, also they don't import their authService.

Here is what I did bare minimum to get ts to not complain:

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Get the auth header from the service.
    const authHeader = this.auth.getAuthorizationHeader();
    // Clone the request to add the new header.
    const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authHeader)});
    // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Are they doing something that I am not, or did they just skip importing to keep the tutorial shorter by 2 lines.

Comment: I looks like they've omitted any non-Angular imports for the sake of brevity. There is no magic that I'm aware of that would do away with the need for the imports you've mentioned.

Comment: ok thanks. That is what i was assuming, but I was hoping there was some magic I could do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Its just not shown there , For code readability, but if you go through
>    their tutorial :
>
> https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#rxjs-imports

There is link to the live demo : [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ko0Lg1g421ePnQa5Q6NJ?p=preview)

Here you can clearly see all the imports

File : app/hero-search.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';

import { Observable }        from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }           from 'rxjs/Subject';

// Observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

// Observable operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is what I did bare minimum to get ts to not complain

This is right version. The angular docs are simply inaccurate / out of date. Send them a PR